# How do I make a class that is also a list?

Tags: python

I want to create a class in Python with various attributes and methods, but for it to inherit the functionality of a list, so that I can append objects to the object itself, not any of its attributes. I want to be able to say '`graph[3]`', rather than '`graph.node_list[3]`'. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Provide a [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__)

Answer (score 10):

All you really need to do is provide a [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__)

```
In [1]: class Foo:
   ...:     def __init__(self, *args):
   ...:         self.args = args
   ...:     def __getitem__(self, i):
   ...:         return self.args[i]
   ...:     

In [2]: c = Foo(3,4,5)

In [3]: c[2]
Out[3]: 5

In [4]: c[3]
IndexError: tuple index out of range #traceback removed for brevity

In [5]: for i in c: print(i) #look, ma, I can even use a for-loop!
3
4
5
```

Addendum: There are other methods you probably want to provide, too. `__len__` is definitely one of them. There's a rather long list of magic methods, I'd recommend going through them and picking the ones that make sense.

Comment: One can also derive from `abc.Sequence` to appease type checks. Or at least implement `__len__`...

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos, Thanks to virtual subclassing, you don't need to inherit from any of the `collections` `abc`s, unless you want to inherit their methods.

Comment: @Navith I was referring to type checkers like Mypy. :)

Answer (score 5):

You can just inherit from `list`:

```
class Foo(list):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

But subclassing builtin types isn't necessarily a good idea.

---

`collections.abc.Sequence` (or since 3.5, `typing.Sequence[T]`) is the way I would do it.

Comment: 'This isn't necessarily a good idea.' - are you referring to the first approach or to the second? Also, why isn't it a good idea?

Comment: @alfasin subclassing builtin types is usually not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You want to add some special methods, such as `__getitem__` in the case of lists.  Take a look at:

https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types

Answer (score 1):

Since Python uses [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), the primary difference between a list and any other object is the set of methods it exposes.  You can easily see the primary attribues (methods and fields) of an object with the [`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) function.

```
>>> [a for a in dir([]) if callable(getattr([], a))]
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dir__',
'__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__',
'__iadd__', '__imul__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__',
'__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__',
'__reversed__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__',
'__subclasshook__', 'append', 'clear', 'copy', 'count', 'extend', 'index',
'insert', 'pop', 'remove', 'reverse', 'sort']
```

Obviously there's a lot of methods here, and you probably don't care about most of them.  But if your goal was to really replicate the behavior of a list, you'd probably want to implement them.  Most of the `__...__` methods are defined in Python's [data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types), if you want to look them up.

From that page:

> Mutable sequences should provide methods `append()`, `count()`, `index()`, `extend()`, `insert()`, `pop()`, `remove()`, `reverse()` and `sort()`, like Python standard list objects. Finally, sequence types should implement addition (meaning concatenation) and multiplication (meaning repetition) by defining the methods `__add__()`, `__radd__()`, `__iadd__()`, `__mul__()`, `__rmul__()` and `__imul__()` described below; they should not define other numerical operators. It is recommended that both mappings and sequences implement the `__contains__()` method to allow efficient use of the in operator; for mappings, in should search the mapping’s keys; for sequences, it should search through the values. It is further recommended that both mappings and sequences implement the `__iter__()` method to allow efficient iteration through the container; for mappings, `__iter__()` should be the same as keys(); for sequences, it should iterate through the values.

The feature you're asking about in particular, index lookups, is provided by [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__).  I would suggest also implementing `__contains__()` and `__iter__()` (and maybe `__len__()`), at a minimum.